# Android - swipe between pages in API 8

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

I tried to develope an android application like [this](http://habrastorage.org/storage2/624/914/b51/624914b519389d43d6b69d63fcde141d.png), I found this code:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging

but as you know becuase of fregment, it works on api 11 and up, how can I do the same in api 8?

Comment: you can use support library for backward compatibility

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176841/android-fragment-api-for-api-level-11. and go through the docs and this http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Setting up a project with ActionBar, NavigationTabs and swipe navigation](http://android.amolgupta.in/2013/01/backward-compatibility-super-quick.html) and follow the steps giving in it after downloading the library of [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Android Support library or Sherlock library. By any of it, you can achieve fragments and Swiping using ViewPager on older APIs of android.

Check the link below :
[This is using Sherlock Library](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-tab-based-applications-series/)