# does fragment manager works in android API 8

Tags: android, fragment

I want to know whether the Fragment Manager works in Android API 8 ? I am using the project to compile with Android API 8.

if yes tell me how to use the fragment in lower devices or suggest any tutorial links.

Comment: yes it supports with api 8.you need to use support FragmenetManager

Comment: Maybe this will help [Android - Fragment API for API level < 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176841/android-fragment-api-for-api-level-11?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) backports many newer features to older Android versions. In the case of Fragments, they are supported via the support library back through Android 1.6 (API 4) as explained in the [features overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html). The [setup instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) go through everything you need to include the Support Library in your application.