# android fragments make it work on android 2.2

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am playing around the fragments tutorial found [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#menu) on section 21. It works fine when my build target is `android 4.0` but when i try to change it to make it work with `android 2.2`, i get `Error inflating class fragment` on the line `setContentView(R.layout.main);` on `MainActivity` class.

I already added the support package, changed classes `ListFragment` and `DetailFragment` to extend `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` respectively. There are no compile errors.

Did I miss something? TIA!

--EDIT---
Made it work. I changed `DetailActivity.java` and `MainActivity.java` to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of just `Activity`. Everything's okay now. But still don't know why I have to do that.

Comment: Check the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528691/fragments-in-android-2-2-1-2-3-2-0-is-this-possible

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace (printed in LogCat); I'm guessing your calling a method or class that's not available in android 2.2.

Comment: Hi, you had to do that because fragments were not an original part of Android 2.X. Fragments came around API 11, which is version 3.0 Honeycomb I believe. This being said, you need to utilize the Android Support Library, which gets included in your project to allow fragment "simulation" in older versions of Android. That's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `DetailActivity.java` and `MainActivity.java` to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of just `Activity`.

[Using the v4 Library APIs](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Using)