# Android Master Detail Flow Example

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I'm trying to implement a user interface like above and looking for a good tutorial to or code sample to learn it. Can someone help me to get this done

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse with ADT installed, you can create a new Activity (or Android Project) and select MasterDetailFlow as the template to be used for that activity. This will contain a Master Detail flow with a simple list of items.

**EDIT**

For an advanced list layout, you will need a customized ListView.

Examples:

- [Custom ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305899/custom-listview-android)
- [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: ADT 20 provide a simple list view navigation structure. What I want is a list with Images and descriptions.

Comment: @cyroxx is it possible to run this template on android 2.3?

Comment: @dig As this Master/Detail template uses Fragments, you will need the Android Support Library. For details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6528757/1388240 - Please also see the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to use Fragments.

Here's how they work:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html