# Android dashboard pattern as fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dashboard

Is is possible to use the android dashboard pattern from Google I/O as a fragment so that in landscape mode on a tablet the dashboard is shown on the left while the content of the current category is shown on the right?

I've tried something that looks like the code below but it doesnt work.

**main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Include dashboard -->
    <include layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard"/>

    <!-- Include details -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.fragments.Details" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Details.java:**

```
public class Details extends Fragment
{

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);

                return view;
        }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at Master/Detail Flow:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773433/android-master-detail-flow-example

Comment: that means I have to create a custom ListView instead of using the dashboard from Google I/O?

Comment: I haven't worked with it, but I can select it if I create a new Android App with Eclipse.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try :)

Comment: @Christoph: did u find any solution..If yes kinds share..

Comment: sorry but no solution yet :(