# Android 4.2 : Application Navigation with multiple activities

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, tabbar, master-detail

I am new to Android development. I am developing a application which basically needs to have a application navigation (Tabbar, Buttons etc) on the top of the screen always. When user clicks(Or Taps) on the navigation Tab (or Button etc) application needs to navigate to a new activity which internally contains List Fragment and Detail Fragment. Same way all navigation Tabs (or Buttons) will have the same content.
For Example: Tabs with title Accounts, Contacts etc
Account Screen contains : List of Accounts (left side of the screen) and Details section (right side) of the selected account.
Contacts Screen Contains : List of Contacts (left side of the screen) and Details section (right side) of the selected Contact.

Each Tab needs to associated with and Activity which internally contains the fragments of list and detail.
How to achieve this, please provide a way to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start with this link: [master detail flow][1] and continue researching from there.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773433/android-master-detail-flow-example

Comment: I would start by reading some of the guides on the developer.android site, you'll find a guide to many of the things you want to do.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html  Also check out the API Demos sample app in the sdk