# Half Action Bar in android

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar

How can we display whole action bar in half of the screen of the tablet?
I usually find that action bar display at the top of the screen in entire screen bt i want to design like action bar display at top of only in half the screen other in half screen something other like image or anything else..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: use master/details flow with sliding menu...... http://stackoverflow.com/q/8657894/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11773551/1168654

Comment: I think you should customize the ActionBar's view.

Comment: I's not possible to use sliding menu in my case just half action bar..

Comment: can you provide link for generate customize actoion bar?