# Creat a listview when I click a button in android

Tags: android, listview

Hello guys I am new on android programming.I want to create a shopping list app so the idea is first. This is my idea :

1. There is no list then when I click the **Add Button**
2. I can give a name to the list and after that add it ( where I can fill this list with products to buy later )

**The problem I have is:**

1. I can't find an idea how to create a list when I click a button like this image :

   [image: add button]
2. How can I create more than one list and show them like the picture below.

   [image: more then one list]

I don't need code, I just the idea and I will search for the rest myself. I already look everywhere but couldn't find solution for it. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to createp a list if you click the button. You have to create the list in the UI or the xml files. If you click the add button, what you want to happen is to add data for the list to display. If you don't know about ListViews and how to add data to them using adapters, I suggest reading more on the topic:http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: but i do so , i wont be able to creat more than one list, do i have to do a list of lists ??

Comment: I would suggest having another page to display the contents of the lists in your current page. I think the UI would get to crammed if you want to display the lists there. It would be possible though if you have a Master-Detail type of UI like the question on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773433/android-master-detail-flow-example