# Zooming a View on android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I want to implement a gallery image in android and when user click on any image

It will be zoomed

[This tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)  is exactly what

i  need but it use the Fragment manager which is not support in android <3.0

The  problem is partially solved using this [post] ([Fragments in Android 2.2.1, 2.3, 2.0. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528691/fragments-in-android-2-2-1-2-3-2-0-is-this-possible))

but what about using style?

```
      <style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/DarkActionBar</item>
      </style>
```

It is not supported in android <3.0 how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Holo in Android 2.3< with this simple library : http://www.holoeverywhere.com/ Its called Holo everywhere and works fine in previous versions of android. The Library is hosted on [Github.](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)