# Error inflating class android 2.2 with drawer navigation

Tags: android, fragment, android-inflate

I am using DrawerNavigator in my app.
I created an android app which works perfectly with android 4.2 but when I try to launch it in android 2.2 I get this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1582)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:724)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:781)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1638)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1412)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
```

EDIT: these lines are also in there:

```
07-22 16:00:52.111: E/AndroidRuntime(470): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abs__primary_text_holo_light.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x0
07-22 16:00:52.111: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1924)
07-22 16:00:52.111: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1692)
07-22 16:00:52.111: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  ... 42 more
```

I cant figure out why.
I am calling my `fragment` (`ShelrockFragment`) from `MainActivity` :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, newsMasterFragment, "MasterFragment");
        bundle.putBoolean("onFirstRow", true);
        newsMasterFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and it crashes when inflating the view:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_master,
            container, false);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case anybody has the same problem the issue was the `android:background`

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

crushed the whole app. So I removed it in the pre-Honeycomb versions

Answer (score 0):

It's because Fragments API was introduced in Android 3.0 (API level 11).

If you want to use them in Android 2.2 (API level 8), you have to use compatibility libraries provided by Google. How to do it, you can read for example here: [Fragments in Android 2.2.1, 2.3, 2.0. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528691/fragments-in-android-2-2-1-2-3-2-0-is-this-possible)

Comment: I am using a support library

Comment: Have you noticed that there are some key differences to using the compatibility package over using SDK 3.0+?

Comment: Not really. Maybe find some small example of working Fragments under Android 2.2 and see what is the difference between your implementation.

Comment: it was the android:background

Answer (score 0):

In drawer_list_item.xml file

remove android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" line

if you want background change with html color code.