# 2 views on one activity

Tags: android, android-activity, screen

I have some application. I would like that this application had 2 screens in one activity. Normally I would use FragmentActivity but required Android 2.1> =. How to solve it? I read that you can use FrameLayout and hide depending on the desired screen.

Comment: you can make use fragment below 3.0 version. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528691/fragments-in-android-2-2-1-2-3-2-0-is-this-possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options:

- Use Fragments even on 2.1 via the [Support Library v4](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)
- Just use any container layout and toggle its visibility using [`setVisibility()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).